# how to create my own installer which check for .net framework

Tags: installation

I created an Windows application with .Net Framework 2.0. I want to install it on different users systems. I Created an installer with some software and working fine.

Now I want to develop a simple .exe builder which checks the .Net Framework requirement.
 How to proceed, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To get started, you can look into the registry to see if certain keys are present.

According to [MSDN's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx) page on this topic, the keys are stored in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP
```

Also, just as a side note, if .NET framework is not present, standard .net assemblies already give you an error message (which doesn't look very nice, but it still exists).

And another thing you want to consider is if you actually want to create your own installer when you can use existing ones that have this kinds of checks built-in. [InstallShield](http://www.installshield.com/) is an example for that.